# How to only show two decimal points without rounding

Tags: r

For a value like 0.999942062, I would like to show this value as 0.99 without rounding to 1. For that, I tried the following functions:

```
x <- 0.999942062
round(x, 2)
formatC(x, 2)
sprintf(x, fmt = '%#.2f')
```

They all result in 1. Do you know how to print it like 0.99?

Answer (score 2):

You could use `substr()` converted into `"character"` beforehand.

```
substr(as.character(0.999942062), 1, 4)
# [1] "0.99"
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `trunc(x * 10^n) / 10^n` as you want to simply truncate your number (effectively rounding it towards 0)

also `floor(x * 10^n) / 10^n` would archieve the same for positive numbers

**Edit**:

changed `floor` and `trunc` usage as I had memorized them wrongly as *@Sotos* and *@Roland* pointed out

Comment: `floor()` only takes 1 argument I think. Also the `trunc` does not work as expected

Comment: `trunc(100 * x) / 100`

Answer (score 1):

```
x = c(0.999942062, 20)
gsub("(.*)(\\.)(.{2}).*", "\\1\\2\\3", x)
#[1] "0.99" "20"
```

Answer (score 0):

if your number could have varying number of digits to the left of the decimal point, you'll want to use regexpr inside of substr after converting to character to locate the decimal point and then add two digits to the end. Like so:

`substr(as.character(10.999462), 1, regexpr("\\.", as.character(10.999462)) + 2)`